# How to determine that input is an image in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

So title fully described whole question.

```
if ischar(image_sorce)
    img = imread(image_sorce);
else
    if ismatrix(image_sorce)
      img = image_sorce; end;
end;
```

But ismatrix returns 0 when input variable `image_source` is created with imread.

Comment: Can we do any assumption over the image? It is going to be a colored image? Black & white? etc.

Comment: @JaviV this doesn't matter. But I plan to use this function only with 'truecolor' images.

Comment: Well it does thing simple. imread produces x*y*3 matrices if they are colored. Therefore you can check `if size(image_souce,3) == 3`

Comment: What is an image exactly? Is it any numerical 2-D array? Also, please edit the last line in your post as it is currently unintelligible.

Comment: I have been testing other ways with `imfinfo` and `imformats` but they are not very useful for your case.

Comment: @AnonSubmitter85 if you know Matlab you know there are only 2 answers for that: 2D array for B/W images or 3D array, with size of dimension 3=3. And it was clarified in the comments.

Comment: @tty6 I have just tested that `imread` with throw an error if the path given is not an image. How is it possible in your application that you load something with `imread` but it is not an image?

Comment: @JaviV There are million definitions for what constitute an image. What the OP apparently wants is a way to determine whether or not a variable is number and its dimensions.

Comment: @JaviV for now I don't know will I use this function as part of another algorithm (then of course imread present), or as a display function for understanding results after another algorithm will generate data.

Comment: @AnonSubmitter85 yes, but in Matlab how else you define an image? Because I have used that a lot and never seen other representations :S

Comment: @JaviV so the question must be changed. I always know that input - image. But don't know - string or array

Comment: @JaviV A struct is a valid way to define an image. One field for pixel values and another field for colormap. There are million ways.

Comment: @AnonSubmitter85 those are really inefficient ways and imread will never create those outputs.

Comment: @JaviV Efficient representation of images is not the question. As it is the question is very poorly articulated and should be rewritten.

Answer (score 0):

> >> help ismatrix
>
> ismatrix True if input is a matrix.
>
> ```
> ismatrix(M) returns logical 1 (true) if SIZE(M) returns [m n] 
> with nonnegative integer values m and n, and logical 0 (false) otherwise.
> ```

If you check its behavior, you get:

> > > ismatrix( rand(10,10) )
>
> ans =
>
> ```
>  1
> ```
>
> >> ismatrix( rand(10,10,10) )
>
> ans =
>
> ```
>  0
> ```

So `ismatrix` will only work for 2-D variables. Try combining `isnumeric` with a check on the size of dimensions. For instance, for 3-D variables where the third dimension must be 3, something like `( ndim(X) == 3 && size(X,3) == 3 )`.